# how do you put caption on figures in sweave

Tags: r, sweave, tex-core

I have this sweave code. I need to add caption to the figures. I am doing this but it looks like I see the figure before the section{Data ANALYSIS}:

```
    \documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=0.2in, right=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\setlength\parindent{2pt}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1\textwidth}
\title{THI IS A TEST DOCUMENT}

\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

<<LBY, echo=FALSE>>=
library(zoo)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)
library(forecast)
library(data.table)
library(xtable)
library(RODBC)
library(chron)
library(xts)
library(grid)
@


\section{SAMPLE REPORT}

\subsection{PLOT1}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE, width=15, height=10>>=
plot(1:5)

@


\caption{PLOT1.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE, width=15, height=10>>=

plot(100:1000)

@

\caption{PLOT2.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

I am not sure what's happening here. I need to add caption to the figures. Any idea why PLOT1 is showing up before the section {SAMPLE REPORT}?

Comment: Check out [placement specifiers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions), for more options.

Answer (score 4):

you can use package [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) together with `minipage`.

here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[textwidth=7in]{geometry}
\title{An examples}
\author{Matthew Perkins}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subsection{Data.}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
<<fig=TRUE, width=4, height=3, echo=false>>=
plot(seq(1,10))
@

\captionof{figure}[Abbrviated Caption]{This is the full length caption, descibing this fascinating data.}
\end{minipage}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

So Sweave basically uses latex. And in the latex world, figures are floating elements that exist outside the normal document flow. This allows them to move where ever they may look best in the overall layout. To force a figure to be placed at a specific position, you can try

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

where that "H" mean RIGHT HERE.